# i3 - Split in all four directions

Tags: i3

As far as I know, `i3` can split horizontally and vertically using e.g. `split toggle`. However, horizontal split means a split to the east, and vertical split means a split to the south. I want to be able to split in all cardinal directions, i.e. north and west as well.

Is there a way to do this in `i3`?

Comment: mod+shift+ j , k , l or semicolon moves the windows left up down or right

Comment: This is a perfectly good question. Why has it been downvoted? (I'm just about to upvote it from -1 to 0)

Comment: Thanks @jaimet. Since I asked this question I have moved away from i3. I am however starting to suspect that the answer to this question is that it is not possible, and it's rather a restriction in how i3 operates.

Comment: @Lucas You are correct - what we were both looking for is not possible, despite [6 years' worth of discussion](https://github.com/i3/i3/issues/1767) and even [a pull request](https://github.com/i3/i3/pull/4794) or two. I have also moved away from i3 now - I have returned to bspwm until I have the time for more hacking on qtile.

Comment: @jaimet Thanks a lot. I would pick your comment as an answer if I could.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @jaimet in the comments, this feature does not exist in i3 and it does not seem like it's coming any time soon.

Answer (score 0):

https://i3wm.org/docs/refcard.html

tile vertically ===> mod+v

tile horizontally ===> mod+h

this tells you where the next tile will be placed

Comment: Yes, but this will only split in the directions south and east. I want to be able to split in all 4 directions, so north and west aswell.

Comment: toggle floating (mod-shit-space). move the window where you want it and untoggle floating (mod-shit-space). you now have swapped your windows.

Comment: That is how I do it if I want the window to be split above, but it doesn't really answer my question, which is that I want to split in any cardinal direction. Doing it this way takes more than one step, I want it to be in a singular step.

Comment: Would changing the focus to parent container (`$mod + a`)  ease your situation?